# Why is setting parameter to a variable is recommended in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one old legacy stored procedure, which is taking long time in execution. It takes few parameters. I had reviewed my SP with DBA and she recommended me not to use these parameters directly into the stored procedure instead declare variables inside the SP AND assign those parameters to these variables. And then use it. I still want to understand how it is important? And how it improves performance. I have read about parameter sniffing but could not relate to this particular scenario, if someone could help here.

Comment: Please post some code that shows what your current SP looks like and illustrates the "problem".

Comment: It doesn't usually *improve* performance, but it's often used to prevent a bad plan from sometimes being cached. See also [Optimize for… Mediocre?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/optimize-for-unknown-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/). You may want to consider having two entirely separate procedures for different parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suppresses parameter sniffing, as the local variable values are not known at the time of query optimization.  Disabling parameter sniffing is not generally recommended.  It's like using a query hint: an optimization done by exception for a particular reason.  And in fact there is a query hint you can use to disable parameter sniffing for a particular query.

```sql
OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN );
```

Comment: as fast as I know `optimize for unknown` is also generating the optimised plan which is suitable for all parameters

Comment: And it's the same optimization goal that's used when parameter sniffing is not available.